# Stokes' Theorem - Vector Field

Tags: vector-fields, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I am having problems trying to verify Stokes' theorem (below) as part of a question.

$$\iint_{S} \text{curl} \vec F \cdot d\vec S=\oint_{c} \vec F \cdot d\vec r$$

The vector field in question is $\vec F=(xy,z^3,xz^2)$ and I am looking over a triangle plane that joins $(0,0,1)$ , $(0,4,1)$ and $(4,0,1). $

Computing the surface integral (over the triangle plane) does not seem to yield the same answer as the closed line integral (taking around the edge of the triangle) so I know I am making a mistake somewhere!

My working is below:

**Surface Integral:**

Function of plane: $$f(z) = z-1$$

Unit normal to plane:

$$\vec n = \frac{\nabla f}{\mod{(\nabla f)}} = (0,0,1)$$

Also,

$$dS =  dA(0,0,1) \cdot \vec n = dA = dxdy$$

Curl of vector field:

$$ \text{curl} \vec F = (-3z^2,-z^2,-x)$$

Working out the surface integral:

$$ \int \int _ S  \text{curl} \vec F \cdot d\vec S = \int \int _ S  (-3z^2,-z^2,-x) \cdot (0,0,1) dxdy$$
$$ = \int \int _ S  -x dxdy $$

Limits are $x = [0,4]$,$y=[4-x,4]$

$$ = \int^4_0\int^{4-x}_4  -x dydx $$

$$ = \int^4 _0 x^2 dx=\frac{64}{3}$$

**Line Integral**

Traversing the edges in an anticlockwise direction, I have split the triangle into three lines. $l_1$ from $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,4,1)$ , $l_2$ from $(0,4,1)$ to $(4,0,1)$ and $l_3$ from $(4,0,1)$ to $(0,0,1)$ .

Also,

$$d\vec r = (dx,dy,dz)$$

$l_1$

$$ \int_{l_1}\vec F \cdot d\vec r = \int_{l_1} (xy,z^3,xz^2) \cdot (dx,dy,dz)$$

$$ = \int_{l_1} xydx+z^3dy+xz^2dz $$

Across $l_1$ $x=0$ $dx=0$ $z=1$ $dz=0$ ($y$ varies).

$$ = \int_{l_1} dy $$

$$ = \int_{0}^4 dy $$

$$ = 4 $$

$l_3$

$$ \int_{l_3}\vec F \cdot d\vec r = \int_{l_3} (xy,z^3,xz^2) \cdot (dx,dy,dz)$$

$$ = \int_{l_3} xydx+z^3dy+xz^2dz $$

Across $l_3$ $y=0$ $dy=0$ $z=1$ $dz=0$ ($x$ varies).

$$ = 0 $$

$l_2$

$$ \int_{l_2}\vec F \cdot d\vec r = \int_{l_1} (xy,z^3,xz^2) \cdot (dx,dy,dz)$$

$$ = \int_{l_2} xydx+z^3dy+xz^2dz $$

Across $l_2$ $x$ and $y$ vary, $y=4-x$ $dy=-dx$ $z=1$ $dz=0$ .

$$ = \int_{l_3} x(4-x)dx - \int_{l_3} dx$$

$$ = \int_{0}^4 4x-x^2-1dx $$

$$ = 32-\frac{64}{3}-4 $$

$$ = \frac{20}{3} $$

And so 
$$\oint_{c} \vec F \cdot d\vec r = 4 + \frac{20}{3} = \frac{32}{3}$$

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Hopefully, I am missing something relatively simple!

Thanks!

Comment: you must not normalize $n$ (you will get 32/3 for the curl integral), i that case $dS=(0,0,16)$ I can write the details if you want.

Comment: @PicaudVincent not sure what you mean here? It was my understanding I should normalise the normal vector of the plane and also use $dS=dA \vec n\cdot (0,0,1) $ ? But here the normal I calculated has magnitude 1?

Comment: I m currently writing the details, plz hold on

Comment: Wait I think my limits on my surface integral may be wrong!

Comment: I think I have made an error in the limits applied to my surface integral. Working out the surface integral:

$$ \int \int _ S  \text{curl} \vec F \cdot d\vec S = \int \int _ S  (-3z^2,-z^2,-x) \cdot (0,0,1) dxdy$$
$$ = \int \int _ S  -x dxdy $$

Limits should be $x = [0,4]$,$y=[4-x,0]$ (bottom limit on y should be 0 not 4).

$$ = \int^4_0\int^{4-x}_0  -x dydx $$

$$ = \int^4 _0 x^2 dx=\frac{32}{3}$$

Comment: oki, sorry for the delay, my sign pb is fixed. here is my answer below, maybe it helps

Comment: Note that the chosen orientation of the boundary corresponds to a normal pointing in the negative $z$ direction. The double integral that you wrote equals $-32/3$.

Comment: @Maxim not sure what you mean here? Surely if that was the case then the surface integral would not equal the line integral?

Comment: Check the last line: $\int_0^4 \int_0^{4 - x} (-x) dy dx = -32/3$.

Comment: @Maxim absolutely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface associated to your triangle is defined by: $\lambda_1\in[0,1],\ \lambda_2\in[0,1]$ such that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2\le 1$ 
$$
t(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\lambda_1(v_2-v_1)+\lambda_2(v_3-v_1)+v1=(4\lambda_2,4\lambda_1,1)
$$
the Curvilinear abscissa are:
$$
\gamma_1(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\frac{\partial t}{\partial_{\lambda_1}}=(0,4,0)
$$
$$
\gamma_2(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\frac{\partial t}{\partial_{\lambda_2}}=(4,0,0)
$$
Thus surface element $dS$ is
$$
dS=\gamma_1\wedge \gamma_2 d\lambda_1d\lambda_2=(0,0,-16) d\lambda_1d\lambda_2
$$
So
\begin{align}
\int\int curl F.dS&=\int_{\lambda_1=0}^1\int_{\lambda_2=0}^{1-\lambda_1} \underbrace{(-3z^2,-z^2,-x)\circ t(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}_{(-3,-1,-4\lambda_2)} \cdot \underbrace{dS(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}_{(0,0,-16) d\lambda_1d\lambda_2} \\
&=\int_{\lambda_1=0}^1\int_{\lambda_2=0}^{1-\lambda_1}64\lambda_2d\lambda_1d\lambda_2 \\ &=64\int_{\lambda_1=0}^1\frac{1}{2}(1-\lambda_1)^2d\lambda_1\\&=\frac{32}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks - another way to do it I think. Problem with my original question is I think the limits on my integral were wrong. I have commented on the original question with the amendments.

Comment: @Ctrp thanks, the important thing is to understand what you are doing and get the right result :)